# Xamarin PCLStorage Isn't Writing/Reading A Text File

Tags: file, xamarin, xamarin.forms, storage

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms (I guess the Forms part is irrelevant) app and trying to use the PCLStorage Xamarin plugin to save a JSON string to a text file.  The text file will be there for cached data in case an internet connection isn't available.

I added the plugin to all projects (PCL, iOS, Android, UWP).  I added the following code to my portable class.

```
using PCLStorage;

namespace DailyBibleReading
{
    public class Helper
    {
        // read a text file from the app's local folder
        public static async Task<string> ReadTextFileAsync(string _filename)
        {
            // declare an empty variable to be filled later
            string result = null;

            // see if the file exists
            try
            {
                // get hold of the file system
                IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;

                // create a folder, if one does not exist already
                //IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("DailyBibleReading", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

                // create a file, overwriting any existing file
                IFile file = await rootFolder.CreateFileAsync(_filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                // populate the file with some text
                result = await file.ReadAllTextAsync();
            }
            // if the file doesn't exist
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Output to debugger
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            // return the contents of the file
            return result;
        }

        // write a text file to the app's local folder
        public static async Task<string> WriteTextFileAsync(string _filename, string _content)
        {
            // declare an empty variable to be filled later
            string result = null;
            try
            {
                // get hold of the file system
                IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;

                // create a folder, if one does not exist already
                //IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("DailyBibleReading", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

                // create a file, overwriting any existing file
                IFile file = await rootFolder.CreateFileAsync(_filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                // populate the file with some text
                await file.WriteAllTextAsync(_content);

                result = _content;
            }
            // if there was a problem
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Output to debugger
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            // return the contents of the file
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

You might notice that the `CreateFolderAsync` sections are commented out.  I didn't feel the need to create another folder inside the app's folder.  I did try it both ways, though, just in case it was a requirement.  Neither way worked.  You might also notice that `LocalStorage` is in use.  I also tried `RemoteStorage`, with the same results.

I make calls to those methods when I get the JSON string.

```
string result = null;

// make the api call
result = await Helper.GetHttpStringAsync("http://www.anti-exe.com/api/dailybiblereading?begindate=" + _begindate + "&enddate=" + _enddate + "&version=" + _version);

string textfile = "ApiResults.txt";
// if there is no content
if (result == null || result == "" || result.Contains("SQLSTATE") == true)
{
    // read content from a pre-existing file
    result = await Helper.ReadTextFileAsync(textfile);
    // Output to debugger
    Debug.WriteLine("Can't connect to the API." + "\r\n" + "Loading from local cache.");
}
else
{
    // write to a cache file
    await Helper.WriteTextFileAsync(textfile, result);
}
```

It all seems pretty straight-forward (not to mention that it works, just fine, with my native Windows 10 code).  Try and get the JSON.  If nothing is there (no internet or API is down), grab the JSON string from the cache.  If JSON is there, write it to the cache.

My assumption is that it isn't actually writing to the file.  I don't know any way of actually checking the contents of that file (can't just open Notepad and load it).

I open the app.  I close the app.  I remove the internet access.  I open the app.  When it's all done, `result` is empty (`result == ""`).

Comment: Well, they invented a debugger exactly for this purpose :-)
Just open your app in the debugger and go step-by-step through your code... Don't make "assumptions" - just check it.

Comment: Would I be able to open up the text file in the debugger?

Comment: No, but you can see there how many bytes you got, and how many you write, and do you have any exceptions, and whether you overwrite existing file or not. A lot - instead of guessing.

Comment: @Grisha I'll have to look into that.  I knew you could look at variable definitions, but I wasn't aware you could check out file information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the problem clearly commented in your code.

```
// create a file overwriting any existing file
IFile file = await rootFolder.CreateFileAsync(_filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

// create a file **overwriting any existing file**

So if the file exists, you're throwing it away and making a new one. You then read the text from the new file and there's nothing there. You may want to try CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists for your file opening method.

Comment: Interesting...  I was using a direct copy/paste from PCLStorage's documentation.  Hehehe...  Maybe they weren't using it the same was I am.

Comment: The dangers of copy pasta

Comment: I only changed `ReplaceExisting` in `ReadTextFileAsync()`.  I only want the last successful result set cached, so I do replace before each write.